# How to Export Multiple 3D Views

Tags: autodesk-forge

My Revit project contains multiple 3D views. 
By default only the {3D} View will be translated. I would like to know how to choose which 3d view to upload.

I found this post where a solution to the problem is described. [Export Multiple 3D Views](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/09/how-to-export-multiple-3d-views-for-view-and-data-api.html)

The plugin is no longer available, but this function will surely still exist.

When I upload the Revit project to BIM 360, I only get a small part of the created 3D views displayed.

I only want to visualize a small part of the project in AR.
My current solution is to display the part in the {3D} view via section box, save the project, upload it and then prepare it for Unity with the AR/VR toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started Revit 2017, it got renamed as `Publish Settings`, please check this page: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Revit-CAR/files/GUID-09FBF9E2-6ECF-447D-8FA8-12AB16495BC3-htm.html

Please select views you want to see in Forge Viewer in view sets of the Publish Settings before uploading to Forge for translation. Afterward, save the modified RVT to your hard disk, then upload it to Forge OSS.